# Como obtener el valor de una variable en un php y usar la variable en sentencia SQL en otro php

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Tengo una aplicación(Android) donde uno hace el Login y si el usuario y contraseña no esta en la Base de datos no entras. Luego de aquí pasas a un `fragment` donde cargo un `recyclerview` con nombres de personas y el problema esta en que tanto el login como la sentencia SQL para el `recyclerview` las hago a partir de login.php y consultadatos.php, y tengo que mostrar diferentes nombres según el usuario. Ejemplo:

entro con pepito y me tiene me mostrar:

- user 1
- user 2
- user 3

entro con roto2 y me tiene que mostrar:

- user 4
- user 5
- user 6

Seran personas distintas y he intentado con una session obtener el username de `login.php` y pasarlo a `consultadatos.php` pero no me funciona bien. Pero si pongo en el `WHERE` manualmente *un nombre de usuario* `(WHERE usuario='pepito')` funciona.

Seguramente tenga mal enfocados los `PHP`, espero que me podáis ayudar, os los dejo por aquí.

**Login.php**

```
    $result='';
     if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
     {

          $username = $_POST['username'];
          $password = $_POST['password'];

          $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']; 

          $sql = 'SELECT * FROM login WHERE  username = :username AND password = :password';
          $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
          $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->execute();

          if($stmt->rowCount())
          {
          $result="true";  

          }  
          elseif(!$stmt->rowCount())
          {
            $result="false";
          }

            echo $result;
   } 
?>
```

**Consuldardatos.php**

```
<?php
include 'DatabaseConfig_Apk.php';

    session_start();
    $professor = $_SESSION['username'];

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {

        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT NomComplet FROM Info WHERE UserProfessor = '$professor' ";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows >0) {
        while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $tem = $row;

        $json = json_encode($tem);
     }

    } else {
        echo "No Results Found.";
    }

    echo $json;
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Gracias

Comment: Si recibes en consultardatos.php correctamente el valor del usuario, pero el query ahí es  WHERE UserProfessor y no WHERE usuario.

Answer (score -1):

La responsabilidad de mantener las sesiones en PHP es del cliente; para hacerlo se guarda una cookie en el dispositivo. Evidentemente tu programa no está conservando las cookies entre una petición y otra.

Ahorrate dolores de cabeza y usá un modelo stateless, osea, sin pasarela de login: cada vez que pedís algo al servidor, le mandás el user y el password ingresadas por el usuario como parte de la petición.